# How can I reinstall XRandR without serious disruption to 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, xrandr

This is the sequence that leads to `xrandr` going missing:

1. Installed 12.04 on a system with a motherboard using the Intel G45 chipset and the E8400 Core 2 Duo and AMD Radeon HD 5450 video card.
2. Installed `fglrx` when ubuntu prompted via `Additional Drivers`.
3. Ran `Catalyst (Administrative)` to select `multi-desktop` and rebooted.
4. Ran `Catalyst (Administrative)` to select `Xinerama` and rebooted.
5. Answer `yes` to about 3 prompts that request to send bug reports to ubuntu.

At this point `Settings > Appearances` no longer offers the widget that allows you to resize the Unity Launcher icons.  Also `Settings > Displays` says `randr extension is not present`.

BTW: This same sequence is repeatable, including the issues with the missing icon resizer and `xrandr`, so there is clearly bug fixing potential here.

How can I get `xrandr` reinstalled without un-installing a large set of dependencies?  I realize that if I un-install `xrandr` I will have the chance to re-install but the number of dependencies is large and so an un-install will cause many systems to be un-installed and I am afraid that will ruin Ubuntu 12.04.  Hence, I'm looking for a more direct fix.  I thought rebooting the .ISO disk and reinstalling would be a good fix but obviously not since this problem is repeatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xinerama and xrandr are mutually exclusive.  You get one or the other not both.

Xinerama is considered depracated.  You should avoid it whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Although the first answer is entirely correct, i might add that you can resolve the situation by deleting (or moving, if you want to keep your settings) `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

After that, you either reboot or reload the appropriate kernel modules, and then you can use xrandr again.

Keep in mind that you are not using the ati-drivers anymore, so 3D-Acceleration may not be optimal.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please don't use qualifiers as "first answer", as the answers can be ordered differently in the future. Include all information in your own answer, or direct to the answer by either linking to it (share link), or noting the poster's name.